# Install Mercusys MU6H WiFi adapter on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 22.04, tp-link

I am trying to connect my TP link Mercusys MU6H WiFi adapter on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Kernel 6.2.0-31-generic

and it says "Connection failed" - Activation pf network connection failed

tried installing DMKS and it fails for the above mentioned kernal.

pls help.. thanks

Comment: Post the output of `lsusb` terminal command while the adapter is connected